# Where is "javafx.base.jar" in the BellSoft Liberica JDK 17 Full (!) package?

Tags: java, javafx

I need javafx for Java 17. So I installed the BellSoft Liberica JDK Full Package (with java fx). But I was not able to find the "javafx.base.jar", which, as far as I know, is important (and my existing project needs its file reference).

Where is that file located in the package?

BTW: I am quite new to Java, so maybe this is a silly question...

Thanks in advance
Alex

I searched the bellsoft-jdk17.0.9+11-windows-amd64-full.zip where I could not find the needed file.

Comment: I suppose, a JavaFX version for Java 17 ships as modules, integrated in the jdk’s module image in the best case, so there is no need for jar files. Check the list produced by `path-to-jdk/bin/java --list-modules` whether javafx modules are included.

Comment: *"my existing project needs its file reference"* Why, though? If JavaFX is included in the JDK you are using, there should be no need for any kind of external reference to it. (You don't need a jar file reference for `java.lang`, for example. It should be no different.)

Answer (score 3):

> Where is "javafx.base.jar" in the BellSoft Liberica JDK 17 Full (!) package?

There is no "javafx.base.jar" in BellSoft Liberica JDK 17 Full.

> my existing project needs its file reference

As noted by James_D in comments -> Why, though? If JavaFX is included in the JDK you are using, there should be no need for any kind of external reference to it. (You don't need a jar file reference for java.lang, for example. It should be no different.)

**Explanation and Background**

Some of the information here will likely be simply confusing for somebody new to Java (or without some understanding of the [Java module system](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html)).

*Java Runtime Images*

Modern Java runtimes and development kits are packaged as [modular java runtime images](https://openjdk.org/jeps/220) and *not* as jar files.

The class files for *all* of the modules that are part of the image are encoded into the image and not as separate jar files.

The Liberica JDK 17 Full distribution includes the JavaFX modules as part of the runtime image in the JDK distribution.

*jmod files*

The Liberica JDK 17 Full distribution *also* includes the modules that are part of the distribution (including all of the standard Java SE modules and the JavaFX modules) as jmod files in the jmods directory:

```
$ ls jmods/javafx*
jmods/javafx.base.jmod      
jmods/javafx.fxml.jmod          
jmods/javafx.media.jmod     
jmods/javafx.web.jmod
jmods/javafx.controls.jmod  
jmods/javafx.graphics.jmod      
jmods/javafx.swing.jmod
```

jmod files are *not* jar files.  For an explanation of jmods see:

- https://openjdk.org/jeps/261 JEP 261: Module System

The primary purpose of the jmods is so that you can create your own runtime images based on modules in the JDK (using a tool such as jlink or jpackage).

JMOD files have some advantages and a major limitation compared to jar files:

> The new JMOD format goes beyond JAR files to include native code, configuration files, and other kinds of data that do not fit naturally, if at all, into JAR files.
>
> JMOD files can be used at compile time and link time, but not at run time.

So you can't just substitute a jmod for a jar file if you want to use it at runtime.

JavaFX includes both class files and native components.  In the generated image in the Liberica JDK 17 Full distribution, the native components for JavaFX are in the `lib` directory.  The native JavaFX components are also encoded in the JavaFX jmod files distributed with the JDK.

*JavaFX SDK*

JavaFX is distributed in an [SDK form from Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).  In that form the JavaFX class files are packaged into jars *without* the native components, which are provided as native libraries in the same directory.

```
$ ls javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/*
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/javafx-swt.jar        
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/javafx.web.jar        
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libjfxmedia.dylib
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/javafx.base.jar       
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libdecora_sse.dylib   
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libjfxmedia_avf.dylib
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/javafx.controls.jar   
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libfxplugins.dylib    
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libjfxwebkit.dylib
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/javafx.fxml.jar       
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libglass.dylib        
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libprism_common.dylib
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar   
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libglib-lite.dylib    
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libprism_es2.dylib
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/javafx.media.jar      
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libgstreamer-lite.dylib   
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libprism_sw.dylib
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/javafx.properties     
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libjavafx_font.dylib
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/javafx.swing.jar      
javafx-sdk-17.0.2/lib/libjavafx_iio.dylib
```

If you just place only the jar files from the SDK on your module path (or classpath) and don't also have the native libraries on your native load library path, then your application will fail (due to a "JavaFX runtime components are missing" error).  This is a very common packaging and distribution error for JavaFX applications (asked [148 times so far](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+%22runtime+components+are+missing%22)).

*JavaFX jar files in Maven*

JavaFX components are also available [from Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openjfx/javafx-base/17.0.9/) (used via a build tool such as Maven or Gradle rather than directly downloaded).

The Maven jar files are classified by target architecture and bundle in all of the native code for a given architecture with the Java class files.  At runtime, JavaFX will introspect the jar file from Maven, and extract the JavaFX native code to a local cache location on the filesystem so that it can be used.  So, if your application uses Maven as the build system to source JavaFX, then the version of JavaFX that Maven fetches will work by default on the same kind of system on which the application was built.

However, if you are relying on a JDK or JRE that already includes JavaFX (such as BellSoft Liberica JDK 17 Full), then it is not necessary to also include the Maven dependencies for JavaFX in your project definition, though your build will still work either way.

Comment: (a) Are there any tutorials out there that tell us *exactly* what to do to build a double-clickable JavaFX app? I've tried and failed, not yet been able to build one. (b) Is is still the case that a developer can only build an app for their own native machine? (An Apple Silicon (ARM) Mac can only build a JavaFX app for an Apple Silicon Mac, a AMD64 Windows PC can only build an app for a AMD64 Windows PC, etc.?

Comment: (a) [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX).  I have used the tools referred to there, but not that specific tutorial.  If it doesn’t work for you, ask a question and I can answer (for windows). (b) for a jpackaged app, yes the tools to create the installers are native to the platform, so the build is platform specific. For jars with dependencies no, you can add the right classified dependencies to work on any (desktop) platform.  For jlink I think you can link against jdks and jmods from other platforms (I’d need to check and find the right article).

Comment: @BasilBourque (a) Slaw created a [mini jpackage tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77410196/1155209) for a Windows installer (including basic app code and full pom.xml).

Comment: @BasilBourque (b) [Jake Wharton: Using jlink to cross-compile minimal JREs](https://jakewharton.com/using-jlink-to-cross-compile-minimal-jres/).  This uses the jlink command line tool.  It would be nice if the javafx-maven-plugin supported it but it doesn't.  Gradle equivalent is the badass plugins, I don't know if they support the feature or not.

Comment: The resultant cross-platform binaries generated by jlink cross-compiles should work out of the box on OS X and Windows and full major Linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu or Redhat).  For minimal distributions often found in Docker style environments, such as Alpine linux, it won't work out of the box as JavaFX will require native dependencies present (e.g. glibc, x11) and those would need to be added by appropriate commands. A jpackaged installer (rpm/deb) may be more reliable in such a case as it may source required dependencies automatically.

Comment: A disadvantage of the jlink zips is they aren't as convenient as a native installer packaged app for the end user (such as that created by jpackage) and it requires fully modular projects or hacks of the launcher to put non-modular dependencies on the classpath.  However, jpackage requires the installer be created on the target machine (and for apple it requires a paid developer certificate as well I think). Also jpackage is more complex to use.

Comment: @BasilBourque  *"(a) Are there any tutorials out there that tell us exactly what to do to build a double-clickable JavaFX app?"* -> yes, [I wrote one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77792847/how-to-make-a-windows-macos-linux-installer-for-javafx-spring-boot-application).