# JavaFX - How to compile uber jar with maven and create a installer?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I need to compile a JavaFX 20 application into an executable Jar file that includes all the dependencies listed in the pom.xml (including javaFX itself and all the other JAR files). My project is based on Maven. I tried many different maven plugins but none of them were able to make the final jar executable by double clicking, although I was able to run in in the command line with the `java -jar` command. The intention is to distribute this app with next/next/finish installers on Linux, Windows and MacOS. The end user profile is a lab researcher with low IT knowledge (I work for a NPO that helps protecting the Amazon forest). Is there an objective way to do this?

I already tried many maven plugins with different goals (resources, dependencies, shade, compiler, etc) but no success at all.

Comment: Executable fat/uber/shadowed JARs and JavaFX do not mix well (for a few reasons). At least not if you want JavaFX itself to be included in the JAR file. Consider creating a self-contained application via `jpackage`, GraalVM's native image, or some other tool. The [JavaFX tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) page has various links under "Packaging" that you can look at.

Comment: [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX) provides examples of Maven scripts for packaging installers for JavaFX apps using JPackage.  I haven't used the scripts in that specific project.  Additionally, Oracle has reasonably good [documentation on jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A).

Comment: Creating installers for multiple platforms is tricky and each platform has its own quirks you need to work with.  For example, Windows requires increasing versions for updates, OS X requires (paid I believe) developer signing certs.  So be prepared to spend some time and (probably) a bit of money to create the installers.  Though there are existing guides, such as those I referenced, there will probably still be some platform and app-specific quirks you will need to work through on your own with limited outside help.

Comment: @Slaw, this is simply not true. It can simply be done with Maven or Gradle.  A gradle task defined in 5 lines and you are ready to go. Jpackage is nice, but you can not compile a Linux application on a Windows machine, and vice versa.

Comment: Do you really want to discuss this? IMO the "unsupported" warning can be ignored in this case. "Right" is even a greater word than "proper". I get what you mean, but sometimes, the better/simpler way might be the not "right" way.

Comment: @DavidWeber In general, I agree with you. And nothing currently breaks with JavaFX on the class-path, as far as I know. But in this case, I don't see the benefit of fat JAR files when it comes to JavaFX applications. Especially when the OP already wants to create an installer. If `jpackage` is going to be used to create the installer, then might as well use it from the start. Configure it to place JavaFX in the run-time image (either via `jlink` separately or having `jpackage` execute `jlink` behind the scenes), and then _everything else_ can simply be put on the class-path with `--input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Self-Contained Application

Your desire to create an installer lends itself to creating an entirely self-contained application. That is an application that bundles not only your code and its third-party dependencies, but also the Java Run-Time Environment itself. Your end user won't need to install Java separately.

### GraalVM Native Image

One option for creating a self-contained application is [GraalVM's native image](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/). Note that this will also ahead-of-time compile your Java code to native code.

I have very little experience with GraalVM, so I won't give an example, but here are some links that may help:

- [Create native JavaFX applications using GraalVM 22 builds from Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/create-native-javafx-applications-using-graalvm-22-builds-from-gluon/)
- [How to create JavaFX native images | BellSoft Java](https://bell-sw.com/announcements/2022/08/24/turning-javafx-apps-into-native-images/)

### jpackage

A relatively accessible tool for creating a self-contained applications and installers is [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html). It comes with the JDK since version 16. See the [Packaging Tool User Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/jpackage/packaging-overview.html) for more information. It would also help to understand [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jlink.html), as `jpackage` will either use `jlink` "behind the scenes" to generate a custom run-time image, or you'll use `jlink` explicitly and then provide `jpackage` with the custom run-time image.

One significant downside to using `jpackage`, however, is that it can only create application images and installers for the operating system it is running on. If you want a Windows application, then you'll have to build your project on Windows, with the same being true for Linux and macOS. And as [jewelsea explains in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77403261/javafx-how-to-compile-uber-jar-with-maven-and-create-a-installer?noredirect=1#comment136458427_77403261), there are also platform-specific issues you'll have to resolve:

> Creating installers for multiple platforms is tricky and each platform has its own quirks you need to work with. For example, Windows requires increasing versions for updates, OS X requires (paid I believe) developer signing certs. So be prepared to spend some time and (probably) a bit of money to create the installers. Though there are existing guides, such as those I referenced, there will probably still be some platform and app-specific quirks you will need to work through on your own with limited outside help.

If you're going to create a self-contained application, then I would suggest you forgo creating a fat/uber/shadowed JAR file. A self-contained application already contains all dependencies, so a shadowed JAR file is unlikely to provide any benefits. Plus, if you're going to be using `jpackage` to create the installer, you might as well design your entire deployment around `jpackage` from the start.

Using Maven profiles can solve a lot of the platform-specific configuration issues. While any remaining platform-specific configuration, as well as building the application on multiple platforms and publishing it automatically, can likely be accomplished with some kind of CI/CD pipeline. Though remember to **never** commit any secrets to your VCS (e.g., Git), which by extension means do not put any secrets in the POM file(s).

#### Example

Here is a POM that is configured to create an `msi` installer file when the `windows` profile is activated. Note there is only configurations for Windows in this example. The [org.panteleyev:jpackage-maven-plugin](https://github.panteleyev.org/jpackage-maven-plugin/index.html) plugin is used to execute `jpackage`.

This POM is designed for a **non-modular** application. As such, it's configured so that the JavaFX modules are added to the custom run-time image, while the project code and any other dependencies are configured to be placed on the class-path via `--input` and `--main-jar`. By having JavaFX in the custom run-time image, it will implicitly be on the module-path.

***Disclaimer:** I'm more familiar with Gradle than Maven, so there may be ways to simplify the following POM.*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <name>app</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    <javafxVersion>21.0.1</javafxVersion>
    <libsDir>${project.build.directory}/artifacts/libs</libsDir>
    <javafxModsDir>${project.build.directory}/artifacts/javafx</javafxModsDir>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>${javafxVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <!-- Lock in versions. -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.11.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.6.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.panteleyev</groupId>
          <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.6.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <!-- 
        Configure JAR plugin to set Main-Class entry in the JAR's manifest. Also, put the JAR
        file in the same directory as the non-JavaFX dependencies to make using jpackage easier.
      -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${libsDir}</outputDirectory>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.example.app.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Copy dependencies into project-local directories to make using jpackage easier. -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <!-- 
            Put JavaFX JARs in their own directory so they are not included in the input directory
            and can easily be placed on the module-path of jpackage.
          -->
          <execution>
            <id>copy-javafx-deps</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${javafxModsDir}</outputDirectory>
              <includeGroupIds>org.openjfx</includeGroupIds>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <!-- 
            Put all non-JavaFX JARs in a separate directory to use with the input argument
            of jpackage. The project JAR will be placed here as well.
          -->
          <execution>
            <id>copy-nonjavafx-deps</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${libsDir}</outputDirectory>
              <excludeGroupIds>org.openjfx</excludeGroupIds>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Common jpackage configurations. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.panteleyev</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <modulePaths>
            <modulePath>${javafxModsDir}</modulePath>
          </modulePaths>
          <!-- 
            Must explicitly add modules since project code is not modular, meaning there's
            no module-info.java file with requires directives.

            Include the jdk.localedata module to ensure internationalization works. You can filter
            which locales are included via jlink options.
          -->
          <addModules>javafx.controls,jdk.localedata</addModules>
          <input>${libsDir}</input>
          <mainJar>${project.name}-${project.version}.jar</mainJar>
          <temp>${project.build.directory}/jpackage/temp</temp>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>

  <profiles>

    <profile>
      <id>windows</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <!-- Windows-specific jpackage configurations. -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.panteleyev</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>windows-msi</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jpackage</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <type>MSI</type>
                  <destination>${project.build.directory}/jpackage/windows-msi</destination>
                  <winPerUserInstall>true</winPerUserInstall>
                  <winDirChooser>true</winDirChooser>
                  <winUpgradeUuid>7c59c875-1ad3-4042-9c9f-fed5fc3f8ab9</winUpgradeUuid>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

  </profiles>

</project>
```

And here's an example `com.example.app.Main` class to go along with the POM:

```java
package com.example.app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // List view will display the modules included in the custom run-time image.
        var listView = new ListView<String>();
        ModuleLayer.boot()
            .modules()
            .stream()
            .map(Module::getName)
            .sorted()
            .forEach(listView.getItems()::add);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX " + System.getProperty("javafx.version") + " Application");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(listView, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();        
    }
}
```

To create the `msi` file, execute:

```
mvn -P windows package
```

And you should get a `target/jpackage/windows-msi/app-1.0.msi` installer file.

Note you must execute that on Windows, and you must have WiX Toolset 3.x.x installed (version 4.x.x doesn't seem to work with `jpackage`, or at least I couldn't get it to work). If you don't want to install WiX 3.x.x just for running the example, then change the type to `<type>APP_IMAGE</type>`. You won't get an installer file, but you'll end up with an application image that you can run as is.

---

## Executable JAR

You can create an executable fat/uber/shadowed JAR file with JavaFX via Maven using the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). Note this will inherently put everything on the class-path. Any code that relies explicitly on modules may break with this setup, though such code is rare. Additionally, JavaFX does not technically support being loaded from the class-path. Doing so will not break anything as of JavaFX 21, as far as I know, but any issues caused by this configuration are unlikely to be fixed by the JavaFX developers.

See [David Weber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77407480/6395627) for an example using the Maven Shade Plugin.

If you want to go with a shadowed executable JAR file as your deployment strategy, then I suggest you forgo creating an installer. Just have your end user install the appropriate version of Java (you can send them the installer for that), and then they can just double-click the JAR file to make it run. Make sure your end user enables associating `*.jar` files with Java if the Java installer gives that option.

If you want a cross-platform executable JAR file, you'll have to declare a JavaFX dependency for each platform manually. JavaFX relies on platform-specific native code, and the Maven artifacts embed that native code in the JAR file, but only for a particular platform. For instance, `javafx-graphics-21.0.1-win.jar` contains native code for Windows, but not Linux or macOS.

Note that when JavaFX is on the class-path, as is the case here, then your main class **cannot** be a subclass of `javafx.application.Application`. You **must** have a separate "launcher class" as the main class. Something like:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(YourAppClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Preface:**

1. Follow the GitHub link.
2. Read the short documentation on GitHub.
3. Take a look at the code.

For Gradle projects, take a look at build.gradle. For Maven projects, take a look at pom.xml.

**Solution for creating a fat JAR:**

Example working JavaFX application with gradle and fat/uber JAR task:
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppGradleNonModular

Example working JavaFX application with maven and fat/uber JAR goal:
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxAppMavenNonModular

**Solution for creating an Installer:**

1. Use jpackage for this. Not jlink Nor something else. Jpackage is the way to go.
2. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html

You Can take a look at the generated jpackage command for Windows Apps in this application:
https://github.com/davidweber411/Java2NativeWinConverter

**JavaFxProjectGenerator:**

Maybe you can profit from this neat tool:
https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxProjectGenerator

You can create complete predefined JavaFX applications with Maven or Gradle, both including a preconfigured task/goal for creating a fat/uber JAR.

Note: It generates a JDK 17 project, but you can change this in the build management system files.

Website link:
https://wedasoft.com/projects/javafx-project-generator/#