# How to make an .exe out of JavaFX application with built-in Java?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX application, I'm using it without modules (i.e. I deleted module-info file). The app is getting build with `mvn clean package` just fine and I can run it with `java -jar myapp-with-dependecies.jar` just fine. There's a Main class that runs my javafx app (lifehack to run javafx apps without modules, found on the internet):

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DesktopApplication.main(args);
  }
}
```

These are my plugins in pom:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>1.18.30</version>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>my.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>my.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I also found this configuration somewhere in the internet when searching how to make JavaFX run without modules. And obviously there are some files in my resources package, i.e. fxml files, css files and configuration file for hibernate. 
Now you have a full understanding of structure of my project. Other than that, there are just dependencies for logic and my classes, that are not critical for my question, so you also have a reproducible example. These are my javafx dependencies:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>19.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>19.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

My question is: how do I make an executable .exe file of my application now? I also want to include java in it, so client won't have to install java of needed version. What I tried so far:

1. I used launch4j, and it creates an .exe file, but the problem is that it assumes the client has Java installed.
2. I downloaded some project from github, that is already configured to easily create an exe with included java from JavaFX app. The problem is that I already have my project, and  I don't want to transfer a lot of files to the new project just to build exe.

I think there should be a more clear way of how to do it, using some commands or something like that. Unfortunately, I didn't find a good step by step explanation of how to do it. So this is my question, if someone will enlighten me and tell me how to do it, I will appreciate that, thanks. 
UPD: Just to make things clear, I'm using Linux and want to create .exe file for Windows. Is that possible?

Comment: The fact that you're using JavaFX is irrelevant for the purposes of creating an exe. You'll probably get better search results on google for this if you just omit the JavaFX part.

Comment: @Michael, but on the other hand, I want my question to be more specific to my case, to get an answer, so a questionable suggestion

Comment: jpackage is perfect for that: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html

Comment: @droid, can you provide a more detailed answer on how can I do it?

Comment: @Arzybek I know, but it's like asking "*how do I make an exe out of a calculator app? how do I make an exe out of a game?*" There are certain details which are not relevant. I'm telling you that because adding in "JavaFX" is probably *removing* results from google which will help you.

Comment: There are many good tutorials online, like this: https://www.nokoriware.com/blog/2021/9/12/java-using-jpackage-quick-start-guide-for-windows Look at the command examples and modify it to suit your case.

Comment: @Droid, I tried the guide in your link, but it didn't work on Windows PC, I was building it on Linux

Comment: Your biggest problem is cross-compilation, not JavaFX...i read it somewhere it was done but am afraid i cannot find the link, sorry...i remember they copied the installed runtime from Windows to the Linux host and then pointed jpackage to that win runtime to generate the .exe and all other files

Comment: See the "Packaging" section of the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info): there are several links there to resources specifically on packaging JavaFX applications.

Comment: You can read the first section of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77410196/6395627) to see an example using `jpackage` with Maven. The example POM itself is Windows focused, as that's what I had access to and know best, but it should be possible to modify it for other platforms. Note that `jpackage` cannot do cross-compilation; you'll have to execute `jpackage` on each platform you want to target. And as noted, there are quite a few resources out there to help with packaging JavaFX applications.

Comment: @Michael *"The fact that you're using JavaFX is irrelevant for the purposes of creating an exe."*. -> I disagree, there are aspects of JavaFX that are different from a lot of other Java applications.  JavaFX includes native code that is not part of most core JDK or JRE installations.  JavaFX is only designed to work as Java modules.  These solutions can affect methods for creating executable packages for JavaFX applications in ways that other software is not affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preface:**

This is not possible with standard things. You must build something by your own.

I can tell this is possible, because I did the same thing, but reverse. I use Windows and I executed the command in a Docker-Ubuntu-Container.

**Solution 1, Part 1:**

The best way to do this is by using jpackage.

Here is a direct link to the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html

JPackage is a tool by Oracle theirself and is included in all newer JDKs.

**Additional information:**

Sometimes it is a bit tricky to create the need jpackage command.

I wrote an application that can create this command for you. After that you can execute this command with a wrapped Open JDK 17 or with a custom choosable JDK. Or you can edit, copy and execute it otherwise.

https://github.com/davidweber411/javafx-JavaFxProjectManager

You can create "portable exe applications which do not require Java installed" and an Installer If you want to - create desktop icon? create start Menü entry? Etc.

**Solution 1, Part 2:**

After part 1, you know the mechanics for "how to create a native executable".

JPackage is operating system dependent. You can only create EXE/MSI in Windows, DEB in Linux, etc.
Especially JavaFX has extra Linux and extra Windows dependencies for example.

Your only option is to set up a Windows VM under Linux and execute jpackage from the VM. You can use Docker to setup a Windows Container.

**Solution 2 (Experimental):**

You could try to Install the JDK on Windows, copy it into your Linux System, and run the jpackage command with Wine. Maybe it is enough to Download the Windows JDK and extract it. JPackage.exe is located in the JDK.

Comment: I [see](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html) that "Each format must be built on the platform it runs on, there is no cross-platform support." Can I impose on you to comment? I presume emulation might be an option.

Comment: Yes, there is no cross-platform support. You could start a Linux VM and execute jpackage under Linux too. Maybe with docker compose.

Comment: But that is not what the asker states they are trying to do.  They state *"Just to make things clear, I'm using Linux and want to create .exe file for Windows."*

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.